# Refrescar el contenido de un DIV

Tags: php, javascript

hola amigos tengo un formulario de registro  con un div debajo que muestra todo los registro la idea es que cuando alguien se registre me refresque ese div de registro con una funcion o algo parecido lo que no quiero en realidad tener que traer de nuevo esos datos que ya estan desde ajax alguna idea o tips gracias de ante mano

**codigo php**

```
<div class="body">
     <div>
      <form method="post" id="form_add">          
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_medidas" 
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>  
      </form>

      <div id="tabla_datos"> 
            <?php
            ...
            foreach( $reg) { echo $reg->dato(); }
            ...
            ?>    
      </div> 
     </div>
```

**codigo javascript**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#form_add").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({    
          url: "post_add.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: $("#form_add").serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            if(data){
              alert('OK');

            }else alert('Error al guardar');  
          }        
        }); 
        return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo utilizar esta libreria [Datatablejs](https://datatables.net/) con ayuda de jquery y pocas lineas de código puedes crear una tabla dinámica en la que tienes funciones como `$('tabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();` y puedes agregarla a tu ajax de esta forma:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form_add").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({    
        url: "post_add.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#form_add").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
         if(data){
          alert('OK');
          $('tabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();
         } else {
          alert('Error al guardar');  
         }        
      }); 
    return false;
   });
  });
```

Comment: vaya que genial no avia escuchado aserca de ello entonces con esa libreria se refrescaria  mi div sin tener que traer datos nuevos?

Comment: No necesariamente... Sólo funcionara para tablas HTML, es decir, cuando necesitas tabular datos. Si tu objetivo es otro tendrías que buscar otra alternativa

Comment: Te permite hacer dinámica una tabla HTML, entiendo tienes un div en tu código con datos de registros agregados y quieres que cada vez que realices un nuevo registro se actualice la información, recomendaría que cambies tu div por una tabla html y utilices la librería.

Comment: muy bien por supuesto que lo hare cambiarlo por una tabla , ahora como se descarga la libreria estoy tratando en la pagina y no encuentro ningun boton de download

Answer (score 1):

En el success de tu `ajax` puedes añadir código `html` en un div que printas en la url donde envías los datos.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $("#form_add").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({    
              url: "post_add.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: $("#form_add").serialize(),
              success: function(data){
                if(data){
                  alert('OK');
                  $("#datosamostrar").html(data);

                }else alert('Error al guardar');  
              }        
            }); 
            return false;
          });
      });
```

Y en tu php creas el div sónde vas a poner esos datos donde quieras que aparezca:

```
<div id="datosamostrar"></div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu atencion entiendo perfectamente  eso lo se lo que no quiero es tener que traer un contenido html de nuevo ya que en el div que se muestra los registros tiene los usuarios que al dar click ejecuta algunas funciones, so lo que ami me gustaria en realidad es que el div solo se refresque

Comment: Si lo que quieres mostrar cambia o bien lo traes del ajax o bien lo cambias en el evento onclick del botón. La ventaja del ajax es que te en el onsuccess te estás asegurando de que el proceso se ha realizado en caso de este sea requisito necesario para que muestres el cambio.

Comment: entiendo perfectamente lo de el success pero en realidad lo que quiero es solo refrescar el div no sustituirlo por datos nuevos no se si me doy a entender la razon es por que quiero que todos los usuarios que esten conectados vean la actualizacion del div por lo tando solo quiero que se refresque